# Eslint rule no-invalid-this and fat arrow function in class

Tags: typescript, eslint, arrow-functions, typescript-eslint

I have following class:

```
export class MyClass {
  private foos: Foo[];

  constructor(foos: Foo[]) {
    this.foos = foos;
  }

  getByA = (myA: Mya): Foo => {
    return this.foos.find(foo => foo.a === myA) ?? unknownFoo();
  };
}
```

unfortunately, in my fat arrow function, I get a warning about invalid `this`:

```
ESLint: Unexpected 'this'.(no-invalid-this)
```

My eslint plugin version is `4.15.1`

Is there anything that I can do to make this rule work correctly apart from disabling it?

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because when you create an arrow function, **you are creating an object that could be called in a different context of your class**. So when `getByA` is executed, it could be in a context where `this` does not exist or is different.

One option is to `bind` the context to the arrow function:

```
getByA = (myA: Mya): Foo => {
    return this.find(foo => foo.a === myA) ?? unknownFoo();
}.bind(this.foos);
```

For more resources on this error and examples on how to correctly use `this` in the correct context, look [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-invalid-this).

Comment: adding `.bind(this.foos)` produces: ```TS2391: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
TS7010: 'bind', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.```

Comment: Try binding just `this` and replacing the `this` earlier with `this.foos`.

Comment: with `bind(this)` I get  `TS2391: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.` It works for you in TypeScript?

Comment: Calling `bind`on an arrow function doesn't do anything, the this binding is based on the syntax e.g. parent function/class.

Comment: `(() => console.log('hello', this)).bind('world')()`
Outputs: `hello Window {0: global, 1: global, window: …}` whereas
`(function () { console.log('hello', this) }).bind('world')()`
Outputs: `hello String {'world'}`